# setting visibility vs. hide/show

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between `element.css('visibility', 'visible')` and `element.show()`. Also, what is the difference between `element.css('visibility', 'hidden')` and `element.hide()`?

**Update**: In addition, what is the most proper way to hide an element *and* all its elements' subtree?

**Update N2**: Which is the proper way to know if an element (and its subtree) is visible: `element.is(':visible')` or `element.css('visibility')`?

**Update N3**: Is there a way to hide an element (completely), but it still will reserve the space/area on the browser page? (as far as I've got it - the proper way would be to call `hide()` but it might lead to the page visual restructuring.

Comment: If an element is hidden (in whatever way), all its descendants are hidden as well. Also, from the `.hide()` documentation: *"This is roughly equivalent to calling `.css('display', 'none')`[...]"*.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Comment: Your question contains three questions, of which, I'm sure, some have already been  answered.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Visibility will still reserve the space in your Browser.

A hidden element is set to `display: none` thus all space occupied by this element collapses.
If you only set the element to `visibility: hidden` the element will just go transparent but the space is occupied as if the element is still there.

`.hide()` is equal to `.css('display', 'none')`
`.show()` is *equal* to `.css('display', 'block')` - I'm pretty sure jQuery does some magic here to decide if it's really `block` that should go in there but it's somewhat equal.

**@Update:**
Once you hide an element with `.hide()` (or `.css('display', 'none')`) all elements down the dom-tree that are children of that element will be hidden too.

**@Update 2:**
If you are using `.hide()` and `.show()` it's `.is(':visible')`
If you are using the visibility css attribute then `.css('visibility')`

**@Update 3:**
That's exactly what `.css('visibility', 'hidden')` does, it hides the element without the page restructuring. `.hide()` will completely *"remove"* the element.

Comment: Just an addendum: as far as I've played with it `visibility: hidden` is not recursive, i.e. only the element (but not the entire subtree) will be hidden.

Comment: Another addendum: in case of `visibility: hidden`, `is(':visible')` will still return `true`.

Answer (score 3):

[jquery.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) is equivalent to calling `.css('display', 'none')` and and [jquery.show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) is equivalent to calling `.css('display', 'block')`

The `.css()` method is just setting the visibility property.

From the css point of view difference :

```
visbility : hidden
```

The value hidden makes the generated boxes invisible **without removing them from the layout**. Descendant boxes can be made visible. [See this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/visibility)

```
display : none
```

A value of none makes the element generate no box at all. Descendant boxes cannot generate boxes either, even if their display property is set to something other than none.[See this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/display)

With **hidden** the element is still generated.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [w3schools.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20111228023126/https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp):

> visibility:hidden hides an element, but it will still take up the same space as before. The element will be hidden, but still affect the layout.
>
> display:none hides an element, and it will not take up any space. The element will be hidden, and the page will be displayed as the element is not there:

Answer (score 1):

They are setting 2 different css properties: hide/show sets the `display` property to `none`,  show removes this setting so that the default is used (e.g. 'block' for a div).

The difference as the other answers point out is that calling `hide` on an element means that it (and all its ancestors) will not take up any space.  Where as setting `visibility` to `hidden` will effectively just make the elements completely transparent (but still take up space).

For answers to your edits:

1. Hide all ancestor (this is automatically done with both methods).
2. Use `element.is(':visible')` since this performs a check on both the `visibility` and `display` properties and to see if the `height` and `width` aren't 0, it also performs it recursively on the ancestors, whereas `element.css('visibility')` just tells you the `visibility` of the element.
3. Setting  `element.css('visibility', 'hidden')` will do this - not calling `element.hide()`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to bardiir's explanation here is good demo of "display:none" and "visibility:hidden" 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

"remove" button sets "display:none" and "hide" button sets "visibility:hidden".