# slideDown Menu - Issue adding more levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I've got this menu I'm working on...

Initially, "level-2" would appear below "level-1".
I've been able to make move it to a 2nd column always sticking to the top.
As far as I can see it's working!

The issue I've run into is adding more columns as I need at least another level, possibly two.

I think I’ve handled the HTML part (see Item 2 - Item 2-1 - Item 2-1-1), the issue now is the script. I tried replicating the current one, but just couldn't make it work...

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vt8ymo0m/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul class="level-2">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1-2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul class="level-2">
        <li><a href="#">Item 2-1</a>
            <ul class="level-3">
            <li><a href="#">Item 2-1-1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Item 3</a>
        <ul class="level-2">
        <li><a href="#">Item 3-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#">Item 4</a>
        <ul class="level-2">
        <li><a href="#">Item 4-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4-2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.level-2').hide();
  $('.level-1').on('click', function(){
    if(!($(this).children('.level-2').is(':visible'))){
      $('.level-2').slideUp();
      $(this).children('.level-2').slideDown();
    } else {
    $('.level-2').slideUp();
  }
});
$('.level-2').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000000;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
}

li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

.level-1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.level-2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.level-3 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: So if I'm reading your question correctly it sounds like you are looking for help with the JS specifically? If so, could you elaborate on what problems you've encountered?

Comment: @Candlejack I'm trying to make it work with more levels... at least one more, ideally two. I think the HTML part (item2) is correct, but I just couldn't add .level-3 to the script and make it work... I'm self-taught so I'm probably making some very n00b mistake or just approaching it the wrong way...

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the CSS, Please try this.
It will help you.

```css
body{
 margin: 0px;
 border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #000000;
}

ul li {
 position: relative;
}

li ul {
 position: absolute;
 left: 120px;
 top: 0px;
 display: none;
}

ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
}

.level-1 {
 position: relative;
 top: 20px;
 left: 20px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: 15px;
 letter-spacing: 0em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
    background:#f5f5f5;
    width:220px;
}

.level-2, .level-3 {
 top: 20px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: 15px;
 letter-spacing: 0em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.level-1 > .level-2, .level-1 .level-2 > .level-3{position:absolute; right:10px; top:0px; left:220px; width:220px; background:#f8f8f8;}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should explain what was the problem and how you fix it.

Comment: @opraatnitt not only it didn't work (level-3 is still not showing up), but it actually made it worse, as now level-2 doesn't stick to the top.

Comment: @HugoGresse was that for me or for opraatnitt?

Comment: @ChengZhaa for opraatnitt

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your fiddle, I can see two issues:

1. you are checking for `:visible` in your JS but your CSS is setting `display:none` on your `li ul` rule
2. When visible, the third menu level will appear underneath the second level (this is more of a UX/design issue than a problem with the JS)

The second issue is easily addressed with some CSS, eg:

```
.level-3 { left: 200px; }
```

The first issue, I believe, is because you are setting an element to hidden using 'display' in the CSS, but trying to toggle it in the JS checking for `:visible` rather than the value of the `display` rule. [This stackoverflow answer explains why this can cause problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8801185/3733680) probably better than I can, but I think the problem is that the JS can't find objects set to `display:none` with CSS.

I've [created a fiddle which gives an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Candlejack/536t3uyt/) of how you can avoid this problem by replacing this line in your JS:

```
if(!($(this).children('.level-2').is(':visible'))){
```

with this:

```
if($('.level-3').css('display') === 'none'){
```

(I have left the logic for clicking `.level-1` as it was, but changed the logic for clicking `.level-2` to facilitate comparisons.)

In my example I've also added coloured backgrounds to the different list items to aid visibility - it is much easier to see if items are appearing on top of each other this way. I hope some of this is helpful!

Comment: Another possible alternative to the example fiddle I provided, is that you could avoid setting display:none on any elements in your CSS and instead dynamically set their visiblity using javascript when your page loads. Whether this is a better idea or not depends on the wider context of what you are making.

Comment: It is definitely helpful! The issue I see with that is that I lose slideUp and slideDown which I really can't.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to lose them, you can put them in alongside the CSS changes. I took the slideUp/slideDown out to make the example more clear as to where the problem was coming from. the slideUp/slideDown stuff can be added back in :)

Comment: How so? Sorry if this is dumb question, but I'm self-taught in JS. I'm still crawling... :)

Comment: I've made another fiddle giving an example of how you might do it: http://jsfiddle.net/Candlejack/ojyezyrn/
However, I don't want to include this version in the official answer as I don't think the slideup/slidedown functionality is quite right. In my view the animated side of things is part of the UX design rather than part of a functionality problem. If this was my project, I would make sure the menu 'works', ie functions as a navigable menu, then add the animation afterwards. That's just an opinion rather than a technical point, though :)

Comment: Addendum: I honestly can't seem to figure out what is wrong with 'slideup' here. If it can't be resolved to your satisfaction I would suggest posting a separate question about it, as it seems unrelated to the original problems of not being able to display the third menu level.

Comment: yeah, I see the issue... in the meantime I've found another menu already with several levels working. It's got a few issues and I just posted a question regarding those. If wanna give it a look: http://bit.ly/1zRkUUV it might be easier than this one. Hopefully... :)